# Java boolean method, for loop not returning proper true or false

Tags: java, methods, boolean

```
public static boolean oneNumeric(String s) {
    String[] digit = {"0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ,"7", "8", "9"};
    boolean numeric = true;
    for (int i=0; i< s.length(); i++) {
        if(!(s.contains(digit[i]))) {
                return false;
    }}
    return numeric;

}
```

I want to return true or false into my main method, but it won't work in the for loop. I'm confused.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The purpose is to check if there is only digits or not ?

Comment: purpose is to check if there is at least one digit in user input(string)

Comment: *"at least one digit"* `if((s.contains(digit[i]))) {
                return true; ..`

Comment: Since `i` is used to index into `digit`, the loop should be `i < digit.length`, not `i< s.length()`

Comment: Um...please don't delete your entire question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your method right, you should

- remove useless `numeric` variable
- use `digit.length` as upper bound, as you access the `digit` array
- remove the `!` and return `true`

It'll will check, for each digit, if it is present in the string, if no one is in the string, return `false`

```
public static boolean oneNumeric(String s) {
    String[] digit = {"0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ,"7", "8", "9"};
    for (int i=0; i< digit.length; i++) {
        if(s.contains(digit[i])) {
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;    
}
```

---

But an easier method would be :

```
public static boolean oneNumeric(String s) {
    return s.matches(".*\\d.*");              //  '\d' is for digit in regex 
}
```

Comment: `digit` array is completly redundant. Also using `contains` you essentially perform linear scan over string `s` - so essentially, instead of single pass through string you are doing 10  passes in the worst case.

Comment: @Zgurskyi i'm not saying that it this good, just correcting and explaining to the OP so he can improve it's capabilities

Comment: Also, about proposed solution with `matches`: String.matches must recompile the regexp every time it executes, so it becomes more wasteful the more often you run that line of code. If anybody looks for proper approach - I wouldn't recommend using String.matches if you check for digit in the string often.

Comment: @azro Understood. Then mention that using `contains` is not good, so OP can improve in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You must iterate through the array `digit`:

```
public static boolean oneNumeric(String s) {
    String[] digit = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};
    for (int i = 0; i < digit.length; i++) {
        if (s.contains(digit[i]))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

If `s` contains any item of `digit` then you return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems. The return in the loop and the i < s.length. Should be something like:

```
public static boolean oneNumeric(String s) {
    String[] digit = {"0","1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6" ,"7", "8", "9"};
    boolean numeric = false;
    for (int i=0; i< digit.length; i++) {
        if(s.contains(digit[i])) {
                numeric = true;
        }
    }
    return numeric;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one error. First of all, an array length is calculated through length without () because it's a property of arrays and not a method. Also, you are looping the array digits with the index of s length.
To check if a String is numeric, the best way is to handle an exception.
Here is the corrected code:

```
public static boolean oneNumeric(String s) {
  try {  
    double d = Double.parseDouble(s);  
  } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {  
    return false;  
  }  
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The problem in your solution is this:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
       if(!(s.contains(digit[i]))) {
           return false;
       }
   }
```

Basically, you are iterating over string `s` with index `i`, but at the same time **use `i` to access digit in the array**.

**Solution**

If the task is to check whether the String contains at least one number, here are couple of solutions:

1. *Pre Java 8:*

```
public static boolean oneNumeric(String input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

2. *Post Java 8:*

```
public static boolean oneNumeric(String input) {
    return input.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).anyMatch(Character::isDigit);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are using index of string s on digit array. Interchange their position in code: `digit.contains(s[i])`.

On side note, you should probably use existing library methods instead of building your own.

Comment: `digit` is an array. It doesn't have a `contains` method. --- `s` is a `String`, so `s[i]` is invalid.

Comment: In that case loop over digit array.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a homework question, so I won't spoon-feed. Your question isn't very clear, so I'm going off the assumption that you're creating a method to check if a string has **at least one number**.

The cleaner (and better, IMO) way to do this would be to loop through each character and check if it's ASCII value is within range of numbers. You can find an ASCII table [here](http://www.asciitable.com/). Notice that the ASCII value of digits are 48-57 (inclusive). Psuedocode below:

```
for each character {
    if NOT(char btwn 48-57)
        return false
}
return true
```